# Negative sign in case of zero in java

Tags: java

Is there any way to truncate the negative sign when the result returns zero; while using decimal format?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
formattedValue = df.format("-0.023");
```

The above code returns -0.0 . Is there any way by which it will return only 0.0? However, I want to retain the negative sign when the result is a negative number.

Comment: I get an error: `Cannot format given Object as a Number`. You should use the value `-0.023` not the string `"-0.023"`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think there's a way of doing it just with `DecimalFormat`, but this one-liner takes care of the problem:

```
formattedValue = formattedValue.replaceAll( "^-(?=0(\\.0*)?$)", "");
```

It removes (replaces with `""`) the minus sign if it's followed by 0-n characters of `"0.00000..."`, so this will work for any similar result such as `"-0"`, `"-0."` or `"-0.000000000"`

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(format(-0.023));
    System.out.println(format(12.123));
    System.out.println(format(-12.345));
    System.out.println(format(-0.123));
    System.out.println(format(-1.777));
}

public static String format(double number) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    String formattedValue = df.format(number);
    formattedValue = formattedValue.replaceAll("^-(?=0(\\.0*)?$)", "");
    return formattedValue;
}
```

Output (as expected):

```
0.0
12.1
-12.3
-0.1
-1.8
```

Comment: In case you are using a currency formatter with the currency symbol in front of the zero you may want to change the regex to `"^-(?=\D*0(.0*)?$)"` (notice the \D* which will match any non digit characters zero or more times)
This should match strings like: `-$0`

Comment: By any chance, can you give us the regex in Kotlin language as well? It didn't work on Kotlin and still getting `-0`

Comment: @Dr.jacky AFAIK Kotlin is syntactic sugar over java, so it should work as is. Check how you’re coding/using the regex. Can you post your code?

Comment: There are many countries using comma "," as a decimal separator. You may want to handle this case also: `"^-(?=0([.,]0*)?$)"`.

Comment: @jackes why not include Arabic and Hindi numerals too? This code is an approach that shows a technique that can be adapted to a specific situation, not a lasting global specification.

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be a workaround to avoid `-0.0`. Use following code :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);       
df.setNegativePrefix(""); // set negative prefix BLANK
String formattedValue = df.format(-0.023);
df.setNegativePrefix("-"); // set back to - again
System.out.println(formattedValue);
```

Output :

```
0.0
```

Comment: Well I have put the above code in a utility method. Though it works for 0.0; it does not work for other negative numbers where I need to retain the -ve sign. resetting the negative prefix does not have any effect as every time the DecimalFormat instance is created.

Comment: You should not put workarounds in your utility classes. Let it be there where you are using it and keep it marked with markers like // FIXME. So next time if you find better solution you can implement that. I reset `Negative Prefix` above with intention, if you are going to use `df` instance again for different numbers. If you are going to use `new instance` then it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0#;(#,##0.0#)");`

According to the [Javadoc for DecimalFormat](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> A DecimalFormat pattern contains a positive and negative subpattern,
>   for example, "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)". Each subpattern has a prefix,
>   numeric part, and suffix. The negative subpattern is optional; if
>   absent, then the positive subpattern prefixed with the localized minus
>   sign ('-' in most locales) is used as the negative subpattern. That
>   is, "0.00" alone is equivalent to "0.00;-0.00". If there is an
>   explicit negative subpattern, it serves only to specify the negative
>   prefix and suffix; the number of digits, minimal digits, and other
>   characteristics are all the same as the positive pattern. That means
>   that "#,##0.0#;(#)" produces precisely the same behavior as
>   "#,##0.0#;(#,##0.0#)".

Answer (score 2):

I find the `-0` quite useful because it informs you that the rounded value was in fact negative (which can have a lot of meaning for some functions). The only issue for me is that `-1 * 0` is actually really 0 and should be formatted as `0` although it isn't with Java formatters.

The following formatter takes care of that, without the expensive cost of String manipulation (especially RegExps):

```
public static String formatWithoutMinusZeroIssue(double d, DecimalFormat yourFormatter) {
    if (d == 0) {
        return yourFormatter.format(0);
    } else {
        return yourFormatter.format(d);
    }
}
```

This uses the fact that although `-1 * 0` and `0` are formatted differently, they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

That by check if the calculated value = "-0.0"
make it equal "0.0"

and you can capsulate the code sush as

```
public String getFormattedValue(String input) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        String formattedValue = df.format(input);

        if (formattedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("-0.0")) {
            formattedValue = "0.0";
        }

        System.out.println(formattedValue);
        return formattedValue;
    }
```

Comment: This works but, becomes an explicit check. Won't work if the value is -0.00 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Faster and works with arbitrary precision (also supports suffixes to ignore e.g. currencies, put 0 for no suffix):

```
public static String normalizeNegativeZero(final String str, final int skipSuffixLength) {
    if (str.length() > 3 && str.charAt(0) == '-' && str.charAt(1) == '0'
            && (str.charAt(2) == '.' || str.charAt(2) == ',')) {
        for (int i = 3; i < str.length() - skipSuffixLength; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) != '0') {
                return str;
            }
        }
        return StringUtils.removeStart(str, "-");
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Here the Testcases:

```
Assertions.assertThat(normalizeNegativeZero("-0.00000", 0)).isEqualTo("0.00000");
Assertions.assertThat(ScaledDecimalToStringBuilder.normalizeNegativeZero("-0.00001", 0)).isEqualTo("-0.00001");

Assertions.assertThat(normalizeNegativeZero("-0.00000EUR", "EUR".length())).isEqualTo("0.00000EUR");
Assertions.assertThat(normalizeNegativeZero("-0.00001EUR", "EUR".length())).isEqualTo("-0.00001EUR");
```

Answer (score -1):

The Kotlin version of [Bohemian's answer](http://the%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929642/421467):

```
fun Double.formatAmount(): String {
    val ds = DecimalFormatSymbols()
    ds.decimalSeparator = '.'
    ds.groupingSeparator = ','
    val df = DecimalFormat("#,##0.##", ds)
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN
    var formattedDouble = df.format(this)
    formattedDouble = formattedDouble.replace("^-(?=0(\\\\.0*)?\$)".toRegex(), "")
    return formattedDouble
}
```