# negative zero after rounding in java?

Tags: java, rounding, negative-number

I've got a strange output after using the `RoundingMode` library. After evaluating this code, I got output `-0`? Does anyone know how to handle such problem?

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class RoundingProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double value = -0.04365321;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println("rounding: " + df.format(value));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DecimalFormat` is an output tool;
 all it does is is take a value and display it is the desired format.
If the input is negative and the formst spec causes the DecimalFormat to display just 0,
the number is still negative and will display as -0.

Comment: but shouldn't rounding be rounding? So if I want to round something that is smaller than zero but greater than minus half I should expect -0?

Comment: The formatter is not changing the value, it is only deciding how to display the value.

Answer (score 0):

When using the NumberFormat and DecimalFormat classes, the rounding behavior of previous versions of the JDK was wrong in some corner cases. This wrong behaviour happened when calling the format() method with a value that was very close to a tie, where the rounding position specified by the pattern of the NumberFormat or DecimalFormat instance was exactly sitting at the position of the tie. In that case, the wrong double rounding or erroneous non-rounding behavior occurred.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7131459

Try with new Java :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use "," in your decimal format?

`new DecimalFormat("#,##0");`

"," is a grouping separator, "." is used for decimal separation.

As others have answered, given your pattern number is rounded to zero and due to JDK behavior it prints -0.

Comment: Yes that because of thousands notation in US i.e. 1,543.34

Answer (score 0):

[Negative sign in case of zero in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929096/negative-sign-in-case-of-zero-in-java)

The only way to get 0 instead of -0 is to manipulate the resulting string.