# Getting negative sign if i get 0 in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to truncate the negative sign when the result returns zero; while using decimal format?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
formattedValue = df.format("-0.023");
```

The above code returns -0.0 . Is there any way by which it will return only 0.0? However, I want to retain the negative sign when the result is a negative number.

Comment: what is the type of `formattedValue` ??

Comment: @OmidNejadabbasi `df.format()` returns a `StringBuffer` instance.

Comment: Why did you copy-paste the duplicated question? It already has a clear and accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formattedValue = formattedValue.replaceAll( "^-(?=0(\\.0*)?$)", "");
```

Comment: Please don't copy-paste answers from another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929096/negative-sign-in-case-of-zero-in-java

Comment: ... as well as the question itself

Comment: Copy/pasting should be discouraged.